# How do I choose a resolution?

Tags: xorg

I have 2 monitors.

The display settings tool says the resolution of both monitors is 1280x1024, but one of them is actually using 1024x768, and scaling everything down to fit.  Now the text looked ugly!

How do I set the resolution of both monitors to 1280x1024?
Obviously, selecting "1280x1024 (5:4)" for both monitors didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the display tool, if you click on the second monitor from within the tool, does it still say 1280x1024?  The resolution that it displays is only for the currently selected monitor.